# Error occur while uninstalling sharepoint 2010 foundation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, uninstallation

I am facing issue while uninstalling sharepoint 2010 foundation. may be this error occur because before installing sharepoint 2010 foundation we have tried to installing sharepoint 2013 foundation, but due to some AppFabric related issue we prefer to switch SP 2010 foundation.

so while installing SP 2013 foundation IIS 6 was required, and we installed it using server manager, but after change in plan we had successfully installed sharepoint 2010.

but while installing another required application i.e. MIM portal and service, there was require for IIS 7 or latest, (so, as we didn't had boundation for IIS 6 because we have not to install sharepoint 2013), 
using server manager, first we remore IIS6 from server(without uninstalled sharepoint 2010) and add new IIS 10 on server. due to this existing sharepoint 2010 was corrupted.

so now we need to uninstall shaperpoint, but facing issue to doing so.

Answer (score 1):

This how to guide from [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5449.sharepoint-2010-uninstallation.aspx) will show you how to perform the uninstall.You will need to disconnect from the Farm first via either Psconfig or the powershell command [Disconnect-SPConfigurationDatabase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/disconnect-spconfigurationdatabase?view=sharepoint-ps)

Please also note the following:-

> If you want to re-install the SharePoint on the same server, it's best
>   practice to go with clean Windows because the uninstalling SharePoint
>   2010 does not remove everything and there are still some items
>   existing on the server like /14 folder, SharePoint Web Services Web
>   application and its application pool in IIS and some development
>   customizations.
>
> Removing SharePoint Server 2010 won't delete the configuration databases which were created during the execution of PSConfig wizard.
>   If you are trying re-build after the removal process, also ensure the
>   configuration databases are also cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you to do the reinstall the OS as you did a lot changing with IIS, even you able to uninstall it but will cause more issue with new install. So suggestions are reinstall the OS from scratch.

To uninstall the SharePoint 2010, please use this MSFT tool:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed